# iOS - Call Remote Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, nsurlconnection

I have a webview that loads some HTML. The HTML is stored on a server.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="Helpers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I then want to call `Helpers.Initialize`:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Helpers.Initialize('someparam', 'anotherparam')"];
```

However, I get an error:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1004
```

Code 1004 is `kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost`.

Does anyone know why I am unable to call this Javascript function? Also, is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: looks like it can't reach to server..or may be web server is not serving that javascript

Comment: Well, its able to reach the server when it loads the HTML, so I would assume it wouldn't have a problem loading the JS less than a second later.

Comment: i would check if that javascript is served

Comment: How do I do that? @sumeetkumar

Comment: if its in a webview then try loading the site directly to any browser or use any network traffic tool like fiddler to see http response

Comment: @sumeetkumar It is served if I hit that page in a desktop browser.